# Random variables independence (aproximated values)

Tags: probability

I have a doubt regarding random variables independence.

if two random variables, let's say X and Y are independent then, this equality needs to be fulfilled:

$P_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = P_X(x)P_Y(y)$

in my case (I cannot show joint distribution table, I cannot embed images yet):

$P_xy(X=1,Y=1) = P(X=1)P(Y=1)$ (1)

From the joint probability distribution I've got these values:

$P_{XY}(X=1, Y=1) =0.239201$ 
P(X=1) = 0.499061 
P(Y=1) = 0.499013

Replacing values in (1) and rounding to two decimals

0.24 = 0.5*0.5 
$0.24 \approx 0.25$

Values are very close but not equal, so my question is:

Can I consider X and Y independent?

Thanks

Marcello

Comment: Strictly speaking from the definition point of view, then unless they are exactly equal you cannot consider them to be independent. However, in practical scenarios, you may have to account for errors due to limited numerical precision. In such a case usually a threshold is set depending on the precision level, below which one can consider them to be equal. In your case, the error in $\sim 0.01$ which in my opinion is too large to ignore since you have more significant digits. So you should not take them to be independent.

Comment: In addition to what @sudeep5221 said, you also need to consider the consequences of the size of the difference.  That will be very specific to as to your particular application of the decision.  The information necessary to judge whether the lack of exact dependence matters is not intrinsic to the numbers.  That comes from outside considerations.

Comment: Thanks sudeep5221 and JimB. Considering both of the replies, there are some more math tests left for me to do to check if the difference remains, increase or decrease. But to take the final decision I have to bring the business into analysis.